# Chromedriver closing after test

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-unittest

So my understanding is that calling driver.quit or close is the the proper way to close the driver and associated window.

However when running my tests, it seems that even without calling driver.quit and instead calling pass, that the window still closes.

I'm using python with unittest test cases excuted via pytest. I've also run standard unitests via Pycharm. In all scenarios, the browser closes as described. I want the browser to stay open to where I can debug tests. I could just call sleep(9000) but that seems dumb.

Furthermore, the browser stays open when commenting out quit on some machines, but not on others with the same chromedriver, Chrome version, and code.

Analyzing the chromedriver logs, it seems it registers a QuitAll command, but I have no idea where it could be getting it from. Could the pyc file not be overwritten?

Code for quit:

```
def tearDown(self):
    pass
    # self.driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The service will stop once your script ends due to [the code here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py#L174).

If you want chrome and chromedriver to stay open afterward, you can add the `detach` option when starting chromedriver:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome
opts = ChromeOptions()
opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```

Comment: I tried adding --detach as an experimental option to no avail. I will try a normal option and see how it goes. Any idea why it only closes on some machines?

Comment: Oh right, not an argument but an experimental option... Not sure what is happening on some machines, theoretically it should shutdown every time. I've updated my code, try experimental option without `--`

Comment: So it turns out the PCs I thought were correctly not shutting the browser are experiencing another bug. I have ~400 instances of chromedriver in my task manager using ~8GB of RAM because the processes just never closed. I have no idea how I managed that. This solution does work for all machines however.

Comment: I have tried this but seems like its not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

For maximizing your debugging options with `pytest` and WebDriver, here's some useful info:

pytest comes with some powerful debugging abilities via the interactive Python debugger (“Debug Mode”), which utilizes the following two libraries: the included `pdb` library, and the improved (but optional) `ipdb` library.

Debug Mode in `pytest` can be triggered in a few different ways:

- Your test raises an exception after passing the `--pdb` option to `pytest`.
- The moment your test begins after passing the `--trace` option to `pytest`.
- Calling `pdb.set_trace()` or `ipdb.set_trace()` from your test after importing `pdb` or `ipdb` respectively. (Python versions 3.7+ and newer can also use the `breakpoint()` method to enter Debug Mode.)

When Debug Mode is activated, the browser window will remain open, and you can see how variables look from the command-line.

**(Note that you may need to add `-s` to your `pytest` run command to allow breakpoints, unless you already have a `pytest.ini` file present with `addops = --capture=no` in it.)**

Once you’re in Debug Mode, there are several commands that you can use in order to control and debug tests:

- n (next): Execute the next line of the current method block.
- s (step): Step through and execute the next line of the current method block (but if the current method calls another method, go down the stack).
- c (continue): Leave Debug Mode and continue the test where the current method left off.
- r (return): Continue running the test until the current method returns.
- j (jump): Jump to the line number of the current method block.
- w (where): Show where you are within the current stack trace.
- u (up): Move up the stack.
- d (down): Move down the stack.
- ll (longlist): See the code for the current method block.
  dir(): List namespace objects.
- h (help): List all available commands.

Additionally, you can execute any Python code that you want from within Debug Mode.

Not all Debug Modes are the same. If you enter Debug Mode after a test raises an exception, you are in the special “Post Mortem Debug Mode”, which lets you explore the stack of the current stack trace, but you can no longer advance to the next line of the method that you were in because that would end the test immediately.

(This is from the pytest Debug Mode tutorial that I created here: https://seleniumbase.com/the-ultimate-pytest-debugging-guide-2021/)