# Any way to leave selenium web pages open after running your script completely in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Ive been looking around the web for a solution to this. The issue im having is that my webpages close immediatelt after they open up, this is becuase the script is done. But, in my case i want them to stay so i can use them. is there a certian way to leave the pages open, even after the script finishes? This is my code...

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\FlashCop\chromedriver.exe"
times = ""
start_page = ""
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


def start_pages(target_page):
    for x in range(0, len(page_number)):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(target_page)
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


while times == "":
    times = input("How many pages do you want?\n")

url = input("Yeezy Supply or Adidas?""\nEither 'YS' or 'Adidas'\n")
url_choice = url.lower()

page_number = list()
for i in range(0, int(times)):
    page_number.append(times)

if url_choice == 'ys':
    start_page = 'https://yeezysupply.com/'
    start_pages(start_page)
elif url_choice == 'adidas':
    start_page = 'https://www.adidas.com/yeezy'
    start_pages(start_page)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is your final goal?
I would like to better understand why you choose to use selenium.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chromedriver closing after test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612340/chromedriver-closing-after-test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experimental option `detach` is what will keep the browser open. You define this option, but haven't added it to your driver.

```
def start_pages(target_page):
    for x in range(0, len(page_number)):
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(target_page)
```

Comment: How can we do the same with FireFox ?