# Selenium 4 and auto-closing browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have script on selenium 3 and it works fine:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://ya.ru/')
driver.find_element_by_name('text').send_keys('some text')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('search2__button').click()
```

Now i reworked it for selenium 4, but now browser closing on its own when code ends:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

s = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://ya.ru/')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'text').send_keys('some text')
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'search2__button').click()
```

I want to keep browser open.

Comment: Please put `time.sleep(5)` at the end, and see it that helps.

Comment: It's closes after 5 sec

Answer (score 3):

I found this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43615712/18476738).

You need to set the "detach" option to True when starting chromedriver:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome
opts = ChromeOptions()
opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to add a dumpy `input()` at the end of the code.

```
on_hold = input("Enter anything on the console to exit.")
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this code out, it didn't auto close for me. Don't forget to change the path to the location of the chromedriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

ser = Service("path/to/chromedriver.exe")
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=ser,options=op)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://ya.ru/')
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'text').send_keys('some text')
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'search2__button').click()
```

Comment: it looks almost like code in question - I don't see difference which could stop closing browser.  Maybe you also runs `selenium 3` and it doesn't close it.

Comment: same problem - browser closes