# I have started using Selenium with Python. Problem I am facing is - Chrome browser is getting closed automatically even without driver.close()

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have started using Selenium with Python. Problem I am facing is - Chrome browser is getting closed automatically even without `driver.close()`. This is the python code to reproduce the problem

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get("https://www.espn.in/")

print(driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)
```

This is the output of the error:

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 101.0.4951
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 101.0.4951 google-chrome
Driver [C:\Users\tshar\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\101.0.4951.41\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
ESPN: Serving sports fans. Anytime. Anywhere.
https://www.espn.in/

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Are you using pytest or unittest or something similar?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to open Chrome browser using Selenium with Python. After the browser opens, it is getting closed automatically. But I didn't put any driver.close(). python version is 3.10.4 and selenium version is 4.1.5. i am using PyCharm

Input:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.espn.in/")

Comment: @DebabrataDas, first off, it's not an error. It does what you ask it to print, then the console confirms that the script finished. Second, that's how chrome driver works. It automatically closes when the process is finished. Follow the link that explains this, and how to supress this action.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chromedriver closing after test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612340/chromedriver-closing-after-test)